# Navbar slide won't get stuck when cursor is on top and page has a little scroll down

Tags: html, css

So I have 2 problems with my code, the first one is that the navbar has a submenu that slides down and when you put the cursor on top it should stay there but it goes back up (it wasn't doing this when the main ul was absolute).

The second problem is that the webpage has a little scroll down (and it shouldn't) I've concluded it is something with the images but can't find the problem or a solution.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/OscarArranz/pen/pKoZmg

```
while(threadopen){
//I needed some code here to send the thread//
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem 1: hover

Adding  `z-index: 1;` in `header nav ul li:hover > ul {` makes it work. Not setting the `z-index` bigger, would make the other elements be "above" it like if it wasn't hovered, so the class wouldn't apply (also setting it to `0` works).

**NOTE:** there's no need to put `header nav ul` right before `.lired`, that's the main reason you'd use classes and ids unless there are more elements with the **same class** and you only want to style the `.lired` inside *header > nav > ul* (which is not the case).

### Problem 2: little scroll

Just change your declaration of `margin: 12.4vh auto;` to something smaller will work. Example:

```
main {
    margin: 10vh auto;
}
```

Again, i would remove "main" as long as you're not using it and set the same value to `.promotext`.

The problem using `vh` is that you obligatory set the height of the element to **x** no matter if it already fits the entire height (also recommend setting the `body`'s height to `100%`).

**UPDATE 1: Solving the weird animation problem when using `z-index`**
Relevant CSS code:

```
    /* MENU PRINCIPAL */

header nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 0;
}

header nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

header nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 2vh 1.3vw;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Didact Gothic', sans-serif;
    font-size: 2.4vh;
}

/* SUBMENUS GENERAL */

header nav ul li ul {
  opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0.83vh;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    border-style: none;
}

header nav ul li ul li a {
    font-size: 1.8vh;
}

header nav ul li:hover > ul{
    top: 7.17vh;
  z-index: 0; 
  opacity: 1;
}
```

**What have i done with the code?**
Removed all `background-color` properties from lists, changed the `z-index` to `0` (solving the first problem), and stablishing an `opacity: 0` for the elements in the submenu and to `1` when hovered.

Optional: you can change the animation to `ease-in-out`, but looks good in any of the ways.

Comment: Thanks so much, however if I put the z-index to 0 or 1 as it is over the menu it does this kind of weird animation and seems like it's bugged, any way to fix that?

Comment: @OscarArranz I'm glad it works! Now please mark this answer as solution so no one confuses! ;)